# ReactJS setState

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a question to ask, hopefully can get help from someone.

I am using ReactJS to develop a web. I face one problem which is related to `setState`. I will show my code instead of explain so much word.

First, in `componentDidMount` function I call `this.GetDefaultAddress()` function to get the default Address from API first. In the `this.GetDefaultAddress()` function, when API is done calling, the returned data I direct setState for later use instead of keep calling API. After that, I call `setDefaultAddress` function which is set all the information to the forms. However, when proceed to the `setDefaultAddress` function, there is some error prompt up said that the state is null. I notice that when a `setState` is performed, the state does not change directly. So my `setDefaultAddress` should put in which function so that the function can get the latest state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
   this.GetDefaultAddress();

   this.SetDefaultAddress();
  }
}
```

This is the GetDefaultAddress which is get data from API function.

```
GetDefaultAddress(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/User/GetDefaultAddress",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        error: function (err) {
            //console.log(err);
            // $("#overlay").hide();
            swal("Error", "Get Default Address Error. Please try again", "error");
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        if(data.data != null){
            console.log(this.state.quickQuote);
            this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
                return {
                    parcelNumber:prevState.parcelNumber,
                    pickup: prevState.pickup,
                    deliveryType: prevState.deliveryType,
                    quotePrice: prevState.quotePrice,
                    shipment: prevState.shipment,
                    quickQuote: prevState.quickQuote,
                    defaultAddress: data.data
                };
            });
        }else{
            //no default address found.
        }
    }.bind(this))
}
```

This is the SetDefaultAddress Function.

```
SetDefaultAddress(){
    $("#sender1-name").val(this.state.defaultAddress.Name);
    $("#sender1-contactNo").val(this.state.defaultAddress.ContactNo);
    $("#sender1-email").val(this.state.defaultAddress.Email);
    $("#sender1-address1").val(this.state.defaultAddress.Address1);
    $("#sender1-address2").val(this.state.defaultAddress.Address2);
    $("#sender1-postcode").val(this.state.defaultAddress.Postcode);

    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = this.state.defaultAddress.LocationID;
    opt.innerHTML = this.state.defaultAddress.Location;
    $("#sender1-location").append(opt);
    $("#sender1-location").val(this.state.defaultAddress.LocationID).trigger("change");
    $("#sender1-postcode").PostcodeFuzzySearch($("#sender1-city"), $("#sender1-location"), $("#sender1-state")); 
}
```

Comment: Please, please, *please* do not mix jQuery and React like that. Don't modify the DOM with jQuery. Use React for that...

Comment: this.setState has a callback function as the second parameter, you use that

Comment: 1. `this.setState()` will change the state some time after you call the command, not immediately. 2. even if it did, you're calling `SetDefaultAddress` *right after* running an AJAX request, which will also not finish immediately but at some point in the near future. 3. you need to make sure your `this` actually refers to what you think it refers to 4. jQuery has `$.getJSON`, which should make your ajax call **a lot** shorter.

Comment: Thanks all for helping me to found out the probelm and give some suggestion. I get to solve my probelm. A big Thank You to you all.

Answer (score 0):

ajax is asynchronous, you should place SetDefaultAddress() inslide done() of GetDefaultAddress() or setState callback.